# Button just works on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am trying to solve a problem inside my dad's enterprise system, the system has a button, that works just on Internet Explorer, it doesn't work in other browsers, so it is not possible to work in this system using iPad or another Operational System... They bought this system from an enterprise called Linx, and i guess this system's code is too dangerous, dealing with queries on the client-side (javascript).
If you know why this just works on Internet Explorer i would be so greatful!

Thanks in advice...
Observation: i just copied the button's html and the button's javascript function, and paste here.

```
<script>
    function Query_onclick() {
        xwhere = "";
        xflag  = 1;

        if (xmodelos != ""){
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }
            xwhere = xwhere + " Modelagem = '" + xmodelos + "'";
        }

        if (xmateriais != "") {
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }
            xwhere =  xwhere + " Material = '" + xmateriais  + "'";
        }

        if (xgrupos != ""){
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere = xwhere + " Grupo_produto = '" + xgrupos  + "'";

        }

        if (xsubgrupos != "") {
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere =  xwhere + " Subgrupo_produto = '" + xsubgrupos  + "'";

        }

        if (xcategorias != ""){
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere = xwhere + " p.cod_categoria in (select cod_categoria from produtos_categoria where CATEGORIA_PRODUTO ='" + xcategorias  + "')";

        }

        if (xsubcategorias != ""){
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere = xwhere + " p.cod_subcategoria in (select cod_subcategoria from produtos_subcategoria where SUBCATEGORIA_PRODUTO ='" + xsubcategorias  + "')";

        }

        if (xfabricante != ""){
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere = xwhere + " Fabricante = '" + xfabricante  + "'";

        }

        if (xlinhas != "") {
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }
            xwhere = xwhere + " Linha = '" + xlinhas + "'";             
        } 

        if (xcomposicao != "") {
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }
            xwhere = xwhere + " composicao = '" + xcomposicao + "'";                
        }   

        if (xcolecoes != "") {
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }
            xwhere = xwhere + " Colecao = '" + xcolecoes + "'"; 
        } 

        if (xgriffes != ""){
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }
            xwhere = xwhere + " Griffe = '" + xgriffes + "'";
        }

        if (xtipos != ""){
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere = xwhere + " Tipo_produto = '" + xtipos + "'"; 

        }


        if (produto.value != "") {
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere = xwhere + " produto like '" + Urlencode("%" +  produto.value + "%") + "'";

        }

        if (descricao.value != "") {
            if (xwhere != "") {
                xwhere = xwhere + " and ";
            }

            xwhere = xwhere + " desc_produto like '" + urlencode(descricao.value) + "'";

        }

        if (xwhere != ""){
            if ( Foto.checked == 1) {
                xfoto = "&xfoto=" + Foto.checked;           
            }
            else {
                xfoto = "&xfoto=false"; 
            }   
            parent.frames.Principal.location = "../pages/cat_prods.asp?xwhere=" + xwhere + xfoto;
        }
        else{
            if ( Foto.checked == 1) {
                xfoto = "?xfoto=" + Foto.checked;           
            }
            else {
                xfoto = "?xfoto=false"; 
            }   

            parent.frames.Principal.location = "../pages/cat_prods.asp"+ xfoto;
        }
    }
</script>

<input type="Image" src="image.png" name="Query" value="     Pesquisar   " onclick="Query_onclick()">
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have an answer for you, but I just had to comment: That is probably the worst kind of security hole I've ever seen! It's fit for a ***TheDailyWTF.com*** entry!!! This should be used as a **"worst case scenario"** when teaching SQL injection to newbie programmers...

Comment: Your question seems to contradict itself. First you say the button only works on IE and then you ask why this wouldn't work on IE. Can you clarify which one it is? Start from there and maybe check if there are any JS errors in the status bar towards the bottom right side of the screen. If you test this in Chrome, you should be able to press CTRL+SHIFT+I and look at console for any errors.

Comment: I don't know, [it all depends on the context](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Oklahoma-Leaks-Tens-of-Thousands-of-Social-Security-Numbers,-Other-Sensitive-Data.aspx). It could be worse...

Comment: Try changing from `parent.frames.Principal.location` to `parent.frames.Principal.location.href`

Comment: Sorry, writing error, the question is "why this does not work in other browsers, just in IE", i've alredy edited the question.

Comment: And just to know, is it possible to change the javascript function and do some sql injection by that? If yes, this system is too² dangerous..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing from `parent.frames.Principal.location` to `parent.frames.Principal.location.href`.

Comment: It still doesn't work, on chrome, the error message says: ".. is not defined"